# Unable to log in to my microsoft account

Tags: keyboard, password-recovery, input-languages, windows-8.1-preview, microsoft-account

I have changed my keyboard language from English to Telugu (other language) , but my password is still in English. I locked the screen by mistake and now I am unable to enter the password in English(I am only able to type in Telugu in the text box provided for password and it is showing the error incorrect password). Can anyone please help me in changing the keyboard language back to English so that I can enter my password in English.
I cant find any option for changing password or keyboard input or anything on the welcome screen. I am using Microsoft account to log in.
Operating system : "Windows 8.1 preview"
Please help me as soon as possible
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the `Left Alt` + `Shift`
+Shift keyboard combination to change your layout back to English? You do understand that the operating system your using will soon expire right?

Comment: I have tried Left Alt + Shift combination as you said but the layout is not changing to English :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your login screen there should be an icon for "Easy Access". Click it and choose "On screen keyboard". A keyboard will appear with which you can type your known password.

After login you can use your mouse to change your keyboard back to English.

[image]

When the keyboard is still shown in the other language you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd>-codes to enter you password. **You need** to use the numbers on the numeric keypad for this (and Numlock needs to be on). (You can't do this with the "on screen keyboard", it has to be done on your physical keyboard with the keypad. If you have a laptop set Numlock on and use the numbers on the letter keys J, K, L for 1, 2, 3 etc.)

Use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd><kbd>5</kbd> for A, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd><kbd>6</kbd> for B etc. Uppercase letters start from 65. Lowercase start from 97 (i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>9</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> is a).

This still works when the keyboard for Telugu is selected. You just need to find all the Alt codes ;)

Comment: even the on screen keyboard is in telugu(other language) :(

Comment: Wow, i see it. Didn't know that it would display Telugu. Does your "Left Alt"+"Shift" still do nothing if you have the "on screen keyboard" on? Did you remove "English"?

Comment: You can still use Alt+65 for A, Alt+66 for B etc. Uppercase letters start from 65. Lowercase start from 97 (i.e. Alt+97 is a). This still works when the keyboard for Telugu is selected. You just need to find all the Alt codes ;)

Comment: thanks its working u r rlly god man thank u thank u so much